# Sharedprefrences not saving?

Tags: android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

When i try to save a variable to shared preferences then call it in an editext it is not being saved? I've been looking around for hours but i cannot find anything on it. I know that sharedPrefrences acts like a dictionary in a way but other than that i don't understand why this is not working :(

```
package com.example.gatorblocks;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.activity.WearableActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class block1Settings extends WearableActivity{

    private TextView mTextView;

    Context context = this;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_block1_settings);
        configureBackButton();
        configureColor();

        Button addTextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Apply);
        TextView simpleEditText =  findViewById(R.id.simpleEditText);
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("classes.txt", 0);
        simpleEditText.setText(prefs.getString("classes1","1-1"));                 //set textbox to equal current class

        final EditText vEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.simpleEditText);


        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        // Enables Always-on
        setAmbientEnabled();

        addTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String enteredText = vEditText.getText().toString();        //sets the array value of block to the editText
                test(enteredText);

            }
        });
    }
    private void configureColor() {
        Button Block1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.colorButton);
        Block1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(block1Settings.this, colorBlock1.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left);
            }
        });
    }

    private void configureBackButton(){
        Button backbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
        backbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                startActivity(new Intent(block1Settings.this, classes.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.slide_out_right);
                finish();

            }
        });
    }
    public void test(String enteredText){
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("classes.txt", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("class1", enteredText);
        editor.apply();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error log? Your method looks fine. Please check if the function `test()` is being called. Try logging some text in the LogCat inside this function.

Comment: Can you use
System.out.println("enteredText is ->" +  enteredText);

You have to make sure that the value is sent.

Comment: @AtishAgrawal The test function is being called when i click a "save" button, and i am not getting any error logs, how do i log text in LogCat?

Comment: Use _commit()_ instead of _apply()_

Comment: @MuratÇakır when i enter "text" as in the edit text the system prints enteredText is ->text

Comment: @PiyushGupta using commit in place of apply gives similar results, thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Try to name your SharedPreferences file without an extension.

Comment: Actually I suggest to use TinyDb instead sharedPreferences. You can save array, array object or basic variable. Also its so easy to use it.
If you want use this, check it;
https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you get data from `SharedPreferences` which is not saved? You saved data using key **class1** and want to get it by **classes1** which is not correct way. You have to use same key. Try using

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("classes.txt", 0);
simpleEditText.setText(prefs.getString("class1","1-1"));
```